# ":" operator in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I came across the following syntax that I think it looks like the ternary operator in c++ but searching for ternary operator in bash revealed that there is a ternary operator in bash (?).

```
var_a=${var_b:-$var_c}
```

How does this above syntax work. and what is the technical term for it? apologies if the title itself is misleading in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It evaluates to `$var_b`, unless `$var_b` is empty in which case it evaluates to `$var_c`.

Look for `:-` in the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
> ${parameter:-word}
> ```
>
> **Use Default Values.** If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

Other similar constructs include `:=` to assign a default value, `:?` to error out if the variable is unset, and `:+` to substitute an alternate value.